# Linebreak in cell of tkzTabVar from the Tkz-Tab package

Tags: tkz-tab

I want to add (MIN) or (MAX) below the value q in this table.

The solution for multiple lines like I did in \tkzTabLine does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[nocadre]{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 1.3}{$-\infty$, $p$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{-/ , +/ q, -/ } %%%%<--- in this line
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} \tkzTabInit[nocadre,lgt=1.3,espcl=3]%
{$x$ / .8,$f(x)$/1.5}%
{$-\infty$,$x_1$,$x_2$,$+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{ , \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\text{teken van }}{a}, z
          , \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\text{tegengesteld}}{\text{teken van }\ a}, z
          , \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\text{teken van}}{a},  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the question but you can use the "help" option to place a node. This gives you access to all the nodes used to build the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[nocadre,help]{$x$ / 1 , $f(x)$ / 1.3}{$-\infty$, $p$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{-/ , +/ q, -/ } %%%%<--- in this line
\node[below =15pt] at (N21) {MAX};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never thought of this solution, although I used it to color parts of the table :-). Thanks